# How to perform an update with optional columns using Scala quill?

Tags: postgresql, scala, quill-scala

I'm working on a legacy system that uses [Scala Quill](https://getquill.io/#docs). I want to have a generic update function in my DAO and only update the columns that are passed. For example:

```scala
override def updateStatus(
    personId: Int,
    name: Option[String] = None,
    address: Option[String] = None): Long = ctx.run(
      query[Person]
      .filter(_.id == lift(personId))
      .update(
        p => if (name.isDefined) p.name -> lift(name.get) else p.name -> p.name,
        p => if (address.isDefined) p.address -> lift(address.get) else p.address = p.address
      )
    )
```

The example above, although compilable, incurs in the following runtime exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "unused" of relation "person" does not exist
  Position: 99
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quill just translates your code to sql, so every part of code should be wrapeed in `lift`.

You will see translated sql code when you compile your scala code.

the `if (name.isDefined) p.name -> lift(name.get) else p.name -> p.name` cant be translated to sql.

And your code has some typo. such as `p.address = p.address`

BTW, it's not recommend to use `.get` in `Option` value. When we forget check the value, `None.get` will throw NoSuchElementException.

Try this

```scala
def updateStatus(
    personId: Int,
    name: Option[String] = None,
    address: Option[String] = None
  ) = ctx.run {
    query[Person]
      .filter(_.id == lift(personId))
      .update(
        p => p.name -> lift(name.getOrElse(p.name)),
        p => p.address -> lift(address.getOrElse(p.address))
      )

  }
```

it will be translate to sql like following

`UPDATE person SET name = ?, address = ? WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Thanks for the response! It took me a while to check back but it seems it solves the problem

Comment: I was not able to get my code working with the exact approach above as it failed with "Error while emitting...". However, tweaking the code slightly makes it work. Instead of `p.name -> lift(name.getOrElse(p.name))`, I used `p.name -> lift(name).getOrElse(p.name)`